# Angular js: ng-repeat, Json string

Tags: angularjs, json

My html code.

```
<div ng-repeat="text in collection">
   <h3>{{text.caption}}</h3>
</div>
```

My json string.

```
$scope.collection= [{"caption": "HELLO CAPTION 1","content":"SomeContent"}];
```

I have to use 'ng-repeat' in my html code even if there is only one key value pair. Is it mandatory to use ng-repeat for getting a single json string?

Comment: Mandatory? No. Future proof to not use it? No. Use it. If your array grows, you'll thank yourself.

Answer (score 1):

No need, if you have only one object inside an array you can use like this,

```
 <h3>{{collection[0].caption}}</h3>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/SEo9u5TJS4fP3EGh7FoM?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

There is object inside the array so you specify the position

```
{{text[0].caption}} {{text[0].content}}
```

(or)

```
<div ng-repeat="text in collection">
    <div ng-repeat="object in text">
       <h3>{{object.caption}} {{object.content}}</h3>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

is the array going to grow during the life of your application? if yes you should consider keep the ng-repeat as it is,

otherwise get the first element of the array and extract the field you need

```
<h3>{{collection[0].caption}}</h3>
```